# Outdoor Wood Refresh

Tags: wood, patio

We bought a new home in April and I'm  looking to refresh and update some wood beams for our patio and possibly some wood walls on the shed to clean up the look a little bit.

I'm wondering if using some sort of chemical stripper would be necessary first, or if maybe just sanding, sealing, and painting would work? I've attached some photos and close ups for the details. I'm pretty handy around the house, but new to this kind of work. Let me know your advice on how to clean these up and freshen up our outdoor entertaining space!

[image: post deterioration]

Comment: It looks like some rot on the corner surface.  That post seems to be quite big so if the rot is not deep, you might be able to shave the corners at a 45 degree angle(a bit better looking).  See how far you can push a nail/screwdriver into the wood.

Comment: Random orbit sander and some 60. Just use exterior paint, not sealing products. No stripper or excessive sanding; you're just looking to remove the lose paint. Keep it moving or you'll start to melt the paint to the paper. Buy the box of 100 sheets or w/e it is. When it starts to have little nubs on it; next paper. And you prob want some 120 grit to finish it and for other projects. And maybe some 220 for inside wood projects.

Comment: I did try to push a screw in and pretty much got absolutely nowhere. It's extremely dry and tough - I'm guessing the dry Denver air prevents rot from really running away.

Comment: Strip paint, seal, prime, repaint?

Comment: I think I'll go with @Mazura's approach, as that was the most detailed. Wood working is new to me so I wouldn't have even guessed which grit to use.